# where does the old value of the variable in assembly go?

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture, computation

I have question i'v been looking for the answer everywhere but i couldn't find it, my question is in the assembler language when changing the values of the variables where does the old variable's value go?
ex/

```
mov ax,'3'
```

if we change `'3'` to `'a'` where does `'3'` go??

Comment: The old value of the variable will be lost.

Comment: It's not really specific to assembly either, in most programming languages assignment naturally overwrites the old value which is lost.

Comment: Its overridden as if the white color is lost after the white wall is painted by blue brush

Comment: Suppose I hold up four fingers.  Then I put them down and hold up seven fingers instead.  Where did the number four go?  It's basically the same question, and just as meaningless.  The transistors in the CPU's register were in a state representing one value.  Now they are in a different state representing a different value.  No record of the former state exists anywhere, unless you explicitly copied it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is actually fairly deep, so I'll give an overview of a number of topics that all touch on your questions.

High-level languages use variables — variables have names, types, scope, values, and many have dynamic lifetimes: they are created and destroyed, e.g. by function calling, by building data structures, etc...

To contrast with machine code, variables are a logical concept.

In machine code we have physical storage consisting of the CPU registers and memory.  This storage exists for the lifetime of the program (modulo virtual memory).  (In fact, the physical storage exists for the lifetime of the computer; it is simply there.)

One significant job of the assembly programmer and compiler is to map the logical variables of our algorithms into the physical storage of the processor.

We frequently re-purpose the physical storage, logically releasing the old mapping and starting a new mapping.  We do this in assembly by simply writing a value somewhere, without telling the processor any further details.  The contract of the physical storage is to store the last value written, such that it will come back when subsequently read.  Registers are commonly repurposed, as they are useful in interconnecting a sequence of machine code operations.

The processor never reads data or variable declarations (or mappings of logical variables to physical storage), so in machine code, we tell the processor with every use of physical storage how to treat the data held there.

Sometimes, a logical variable's lifetime ends (so the mapping is done), for example, a function returns (so it input parameters and local variables are destroyed) but the physical storage that a variable was mapped to is not immediately reused/repurposed by the program — in that case, the last value of that variable lives on in that storage location.

This tells us, though, that in assembly it is easy to have logic errors, such as uninitialized variables, which appear to have random or garbage values (but they are not truly random as there is an effect from the repurposing of physical storage, that if not fully replaced/fully initialized, physical storage will remember the last thing it was told to remember, perhaps from an earlier mapping of a different logical variable to that same storage).  Modern languages do analysis to prevent uninitialized variables and certain other kinds of logic errors (e.g. type checking), but these error checks (mostly) don't happen in assembly, so such correctness is programmer responsibility.

Physical storage is accomplished via electronic circuits.  A feedback loop in circuitry allows a bit (binary digit, 1 or 0) to be remembered until changed.  (Wiring an output back to an input of the storage circuit creates that feedback loop.)  Internally, individual storage bits can be: cleared to 0, set to 1, read to reveal the last value they were told to store.  Groupings of bits allow storing larger numbers, like `ax` which is 16 storage bits grouped together.

Old values are forgotten in order to store new values — the gates storing binary digits are charged or discharged as needed in order to store the new values.  So, some of the old values, as charges, are reused (e.g. if a bit of the new value happens to be the same as that bit in the previous value), and if you will, some old values turn into electricity that is dissipated, usually as heat, e.g. perhaps if a 1 as previous bit value is being changed into a 0, then that 1 is discharged.

---

In summary, variables are a logical concept of our pseudo code and high-level programming languages.  They come and go as our algorithms dictate.  Physical storage is always there, frequently being repurposed (by a machine code program) for different logical variables of our algorithms.  Hardware stores bits using feedback loops in circuitry, and electrically charges and discharges physical storage bits as needed to hold new values, as per the machine code program's instructions, while the old values may escape as lost energy.

Next time you feel heat from your laptop, think of all those old values escaping!